# reveal.js: Blurry font in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms, reveal.js

I want to create a presentation using reveal.js. The slides are automatically scaled to fit the browser window.

However, in Firefox (47), the font is really blurry, both on Windows 10 and Fedora. Chrome looks fine on both systems, so does Edge.

I've put a comparison image below: It shows the 'V' from the [reveal.js demo page](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/). As you can see, Chrome and Edge have about 1 pixel of "antialiasing boarder", while Firefox shows about 3 pixel. That's really hard on the eye...

[image: Font comparison]

What can I do to get a crisper presentation in FF?